# Reset D3 zoom translate

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a draggable element in D3 that doesn't drag beyond the page. 
Like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhwpff2r/1/

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10};
var width = 600;
var height = 600;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom);

rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

svg.append("g")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rectangle")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

function zoomed() {
    console.log('1: ', zoom.translate());
    if (zoom.translate()[0] > 0) {
        //zoom.translate([0, zoom.translate()[1]]);
        //console.log('2: ', zoom.translate());
    }
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.translate() + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")");
}
```

[image]

In other words, I don't want to see the background behind the red rectangle.

For this I'm checking whether the `zoom.translate()[0]` is bigger than `0` and manually setting it to `0`.

This works fine, but the problem is that when I drag to the left again the `zoom.translate()` **x** value is still the original one, not the one that I manually set (unless I release the mouse click before dragging to the left).

Does anyone know how I make the `zoom.translate` value persist?

Thanks.